# Response not being returned when object is inserted

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

I have some form data and I am using spring boot and I am sending the POST request through AJAX and it is successfully being inserted in database.But,Since it is being inserted in database ,I am expecting the response,But the response is not coming in **console.log(response).**

The data of form is successfully inserted on database as my ajax code is:

```
var employee={
      "iNumber":$("#iNumber").val(),
       "fullName":$("#fullName").val(),
       "joinedDate":$("#joinedDate").val(),
         "position":$("#position").val(),
       "reportsTo":$("#reportsTo").val(),
        "cubicleNo":$("#cubicleNo").val(),
      "jobType":$("#jobType").val()
};

$.ajax({
                    url: A_PAGE_CONTEXT_PATH + "/insert-emp",
                    method: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(employee),
                      success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            }, error: function(response){
                        switch(response.status){
                            case 409:
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The Rest Api is:

```
package com.ashwin.vemployee.restcontroller;

import com.ashwin.vemployee.model.Employee;
import com.ashwin.vemployee.response.ResponseMessage;
import com.ashwin.vemployee.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.URI;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService empService;

  @PostMapping("/insert-emp")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee){
        Employee savedUser= empService.saveEmployee(employee);



        //return status of HTtp after created
       URI location= ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").
               buildAndExpand(savedUser.getiNumber()).toUri();
       return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
}
```

The service class is:

```
package com.ashwin.vemployee.service;

import com.ashwin.vemployee.model.Employee;
import com.ashwin.vemployee.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepository;

    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee){
        if(employee.getiNumber()==0){
            empRepository.save(employee);
        }
        else{
            empRepository.save(employee);
        }
        return  employee;
    }

}
```

The repository is:

```
package com.ashwin.vemployee.repository;

import com.ashwin.vemployee.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface  EmployeeRepository  extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
}
```

The data is successfully inserted on database but the response is coming nothing in my `console.log(response).`

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ashwin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vemployee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>vemployee</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot for offc</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- needed for jsp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--bootsrap and jquery-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap-datepicker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My model class Employee.java is :

```
package com.ashwin.vemployee.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer iNumber;

    @NotBlank
    private String fullName;

//    @NotBlank
    private String joinedDate;

    @NotBlank
    private String position;

    @NotBlank
    private String reportsTo;

    @NotBlank
    private String cubicleNo;

    @NotBlank
    private String jobType;


    public Employee() {
    }

    public Integer getiNumber() {
        return iNumber;
    }

    public void setiNumber(Integer iNumber) {
        this.iNumber = iNumber;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getJoinedDate() {
        return joinedDate;
    }

    public void setJoinedDate(String joinedDate) {
        this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getReportsTo() {
        return reportsTo;
    }

    public void setReportsTo(String reportsTo) {
        this.reportsTo = reportsTo;
    }

    public String getCubicleNo() {
        return cubicleNo;
    }

    public void setCubicleNo(String cubicleNo) {
        this.cubicleNo = cubicleNo;
    }

    public String getJobType() {
        return jobType;
    }

    public void setJobType(String jobType) {
        this.jobType = jobType;
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of response exactly is returned?

Comment: Nothing comes in console.why is it so?

Comment: Because not every case is logged, thats why I'm asking for the exact response in terms of response status. If the database contains a record and `savedUser` equals the record, then the place to search for the information getting lost are the layers in between.

Comment: Post edited please see

Answer (score 0):

You din't set anything in response body, you can set it like this - 
`ResponseEntity.created(location).body(savedUser).build()`